# Get Unicode Text from SQLite DB

Tags: sqlite, unicode, livecode

I have an SQLite database that contains values with strange characters like ü, é, etc. SQLite is UTF8 by default and the values look good in a database tool.

Now I need to fill an option menu in Livecode with these values. 
When I do

```
put uniencode ("KrÃ¼ger", "utf8") into tData
set the text of button "option" to tDAta
```

I get the correct value in the option button but looking strange with big spacings like `"K r ü g e r"` instead of `"Krüger"`
Edit: It appears to be that the Text is displayed in "full width". I am using Tahoma but changing the font does not make a difference.

If I don't do uniencode I get `"KrÃ¼ger"`.

I also tried `set the unicodetext of button "option" to tData` but that gave me one line of chinese or japanse chars or so.

Where is my mistake?

I am using Livecode 7.0.6.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I made an error when Importing the data into the DB so it doesn't seem to be UTF8 at the beginning. I am editing the tables now directly and won't do another re-import so that should be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      put textDecode(MyVariable,”UTF8”) into NewVariable
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just read up on it in the release notes and that is something I'll definitely do with all text going into the db.

Comment: This is for going the other way...coming in from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The uniencode and unidecode functions are deprecated as of LiveCode 7. In your example, try:

```
put revDataFromQuery(,, tConnectionId, tQuery) into tUTF8data
set the text of button "option" to textDecode(tUTF8data,"utf8")
```

Comment: Thanks! I just removed all `uniencode` and `unidecode` from my code and do an `textdecode` on loading the data from the DB. Solved the remaining unicode troubles I had